# Is "Apex Saecula" a correct translation for "The pinnacle of the ages/centuries"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I'm trying to find a fitting title for my French novel that would stand the test of translation in most European languages. I went for a Latin title but I'm not sure whether it's declined correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You need the plural genitive of [*saeculum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saeculum#Latin) (an age, a century), which is *saeculorum,* "of the ages".

I think **apex saeculorum** is fine. Most educated people from European countries will instantly grasp the meaning as well as feel the gravitas of its expression in Latin. Lewis & Short report *apex* used to mean "the highest honor" or "the crown" in sense II.C.2 [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=apex). One of the cited passages is from Cicero, *De Senectute* [17.61](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/marcus_tullius_cicero-de_senectute/1923/pb_LCL154.73.xml?rskey=YReQ59&result=1&mainRsKey=eHJaDq):

> **Apex** est autem senectutis auctoritas.
>
> But the **crowning glory** of old age is influence [authority].

I am not an expert on Latin, though, so you should wait at least until this answer gets a few upvotes before accepting it, which will also allow time for a better answer or a critical comment to be posted. (I'll post a competing answer myself in a moment so people can vote on it.)

Answer (score 3):

*Summum,* a synonym of *apex* and the root of English "summit" and French "sommet", might be a better translation from a purist standpoint, since I think *summum* is more often used in the extended sense of "the epitome" or "the pinnacle". Its meaning might be less clear, though, to people who haven't studied Latin.

I googled a little and found precedent in a couple phrases, including this line by the Venerable Bede:

> Apparebunt ante **summum saeculorum** iudicem.
>
> They appeared before the **supreme** judge **of the ages**.

*Summum* is primarily an adjective (really, a determiner), here modifying *iudicem,* though it is often used as a substantive.

It might appear better to use *summum* as an adjective like this: **summum saeculum**, "the peak age", but this means "the pinnacle of [a specific] century."

John Updike's short story *Bech Presides* has a character coin the phrase [*summa saeculorum*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MuaLDQAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA109&dq=%22summa%20saeculorum%22&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q=%22summa%20saeculorum%22&f=false), following the pattern of titles of famous works such as [*Summa Theologica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summa_Theologica), where the plural *summa* means "the high points, the main ideas", whence the English word "summary".

(Now that I've researched this and written it out, I'm definitely preferring **apex saeculorum** over **summum saeculorum**.)